# How to Find many Number in Textbox in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, parsing

i have textbox with text is `"ab1234de524sfe6985dsef456"` and i want take all number in this to array
like

```
arr(0)=1234,
arr(1)=524,
arr(2)=6985,
arr(3)=456
```

help me, thanks

Comment: The text looks like hexadecimal numbers with the delimiter s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Check out following code snippet that is written in c#

```
string strRegex = @"\d+";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @"ab1234de524sfe6985dsef456";
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    list.Add(myMatch.Value);
  }
}

list.Dump();
```

Comment: sorry i'm tag c# but i use visual basic. can you help me covert to visual basic, thanks very much

Comment: This is Java code :)  You must properly tag your question if you don't know how to convert @Lulu.

Answer (score 0):

Converted to Visual Basic:

```
Dim strRegex As String = "\d+"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim strTargetString As String = "ab1234de524sfe6985dsef456"
Dim list As New ArrayList()
For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
    If myMatch.Success Then
        list.Add(myMatch.Value)
    End If
Next
```